# MYSQL: How to select a common table expression into a temporary table

Tags: mysql

I installed the XAMPP stack and am using PHPMYADMIN and MariaDB version 10.4.11.
Although I can get common table expressions and temporary tables to work separately, I can't figure out how to select a common table expression into a temp table, or find any example of this on the internet. Here is a simple code sample of what I want to do.

```
with recursive cte (firstValue, secondValue) AS
(select "FirstValue", "SecondValue")

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Sample Data: [id, name, parentid, order] (99, "ten", 75, 20) (75, "one", NULL, 20) (54, "hi", 75, 10) (12, "bye", 54, 3)

Required Result: [id, name, parentid, order] (75, "one", NULL, 20) (54, "hi", 75, 10) (12, "bye", 54, 3) (99, "ten", 75, 20)

Comment: I am trying to get the rows of a self referencing table into a certain order, because it has to represent a tree hierarchy, and then display this on a web page using PHP. It is for a job interview, and they gave very specific guidelines on what they consider to be clean code, like make few database calls, try and have a single query do all the work instead of multiple queries and also to use as few loops as possible for the PHP part. Common table expressions do not seem to preserve order, which is why I thought a temporary table would be the way to go.

Comment: Sample data and expected outcome would help.

Comment: *Common table expressions do not seem to preserve order* None preserves the ordering except the output. Exclusion - in subquery/CTE ordering is preserved until LIMIT is applied (and immediately after applying the ordering is lost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTE is a part of SELECT query part, not a part of whole query. So

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp 
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS ( SELECT 'FirstValue' firstValue, 
                'SecondValue' secondValue )
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=444e2ec2a67d93844b729ce1eebe6111)